# Rails 4 - Google One Time Code Flow with omniauth-google-oauth2, keep getting "Invalid code"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have a Rails app in which I want users to be able to sign in / up with Google. I'm using the following gem:

```
#gemfile
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

I've almost got it to work (I actually received the access token once, not sure why) - but before getting the access_token I constantly get the following error:

```
"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"Invalid code."
```

I have checked so that the code is unique for each request and that it isn't nil. The relevant parts of the method where I try to get the `access_token` after I've received the one time authorisation code looks like this:

```
def google_authentication
  respond_to do |format|
    # authorisation code

    code = params[:code]
    unless code.blank?

      client_id = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
      client_secret = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
      redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
      grant_type = 'authorization_code'

      load = {client_id: client_id, client_secret: client_secret,  redirect_uri: redirect_uri, grant_type: grant_type, code: code}
      payload = load.to_json
      url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token"
      response = HTTParty.post(url, :query => load)

      json = JSON.parse(response.body)

      unless json.nil?
        unless json[:error].present?
          # TODO: Handle data      
          format.json { render :json => {:message => "Success"} }              
        else
          # ERROR "Invalid code" always happen
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In Google's developer console I have the following credentials:

```
Client ID           [CLient ID]
Email address       [Email]
Client secret       [Secret]
Redirect URIs       http://127.0.0.1:3000/
JavaScript origins  http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Would be thankful for any ideas or tips.

**Update for completion**

This is how I set up omniauth-google-oauth2:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],  ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    {
      :scope => "email, profile",
      :prompt => "select_account",
      :provider_ignores_state => true
    }
end
```

**Update 2**

As mentioned above I once managed to get the access token once, I managed to reproduce it again. I did it by clicking my sign in button three times.The first time I got:

```
"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"Invalid code."
```

The second click resulted in:

```
"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"Code was already redeemed."
```

And the third time I successfully got the `access_token`. I find it really strange that I sometimes get the `access_token`, but most of the time get:

```
"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"Invalid code."
```

And the success / error "rate" isn't 100% consistent. Sometimes it takes more than three clicks. I find it quite strange that it sometimes works and that I sometimes get different error responses without changing anything in my code.

Could it be related to time / expiration date of the code?

**Update 3**

For additional completion. This is how my Javascript (or CoffeeScript) looks like when the user clicks the Google Sign in button:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax
    url: 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plus.js?onload=gpAsyncInit'
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.gpAsyncInit = ->
  $('.googleplus-login').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    gapi.auth.authorize {
      immediate: false
      response_type: 'code'
      cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin'
      client_id: '[id]'
      scope: 'email profile'
    }, (response) ->
      if response and !response.error

        jQuery.ajax
          type: 'POST'
          url: '/auth/google_oauth2/callback'
          dataType: 'json'
          data: response
          success: (json) ->
            # response from server
            console.log "JSON: " + json
            return
      else
        # google authentication failed
```

Comment: I notice the line `payload = load.to_json` is not being used. I would remove it and make sure your current code is not using `payload` for the query param in your HTTParty request.

Comment: One other shot in the dark here. Playing around with the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), I notice that the authorization codes are Base64 encoded which can include characters like `/` which may be url-encoded as `%2F`. Have you checked the `params[:code]` value you're passing to the token request to confirm it's encoding properly? For example, if you got back the code `4/K` as `4%2Fk` and passed that along as the HTTParty query, it's possible it might get encoded as `4%252Fk` which would lead to the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. When I `puts` my code locally it seems to be encoded correct, like: `4/I-`. Do you think I need to URL encode it before sending it?

Comment: @klenwell I also noticed that if I past one of my codes into the playground I also get the `Invalid code` error, while the default code in the playground works.

Comment: @klenwell Managed to get the access_token once again, but it's not working every time. Updated my question, any more ideas? :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to url-encode your `code` value. HTTParty will handle that. That doesn't seem to be your issue. Also, I wouldn't expect your authorization code to work in the playground since it will use different client credentials. Regrettably, no other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ...as it is wrote:

> Authorized redirect 
>   URIs One URI per line. Needs to have a protocol,
>   no URL fragments, and no relative paths. Can't be a public IP Address.

Your setting:

> Redirect URIs       http://127.0.0.1:3000/ 
>   JavaScript origins  http://127.0.0.1:3000/

...is wrong.

It should be:

> Redirect URIs: http://my.true.domain/users/auth/google/callback

and

```
 provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],  ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    {
      :scope => "email, profile",
      :name => "google",
      ...
```

I hope it help!

Comment: Hmmm, seems like I got it to work - still using 127.0.0.1:3000. Adding name => "google" could possibly have done the trick. It have at least worked three times in a row, will do some more testing, it it keeps working then I will accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I cant help with the ruby part but I may be able to help you figure out what's wrong.

There are in fact 3 codes returned by Google's authentication server.  Authorization code, Access token, and refresh token.

- **Authorization code** can only be used once to get the first refresh token.
- **Access Token** used to access data on the apis, expires after an hour.
- **Refresh Token** used to get a new access token when it expires.  good until the user removes access.

**Authorization code**

This is the code that gets returned when the user hits accept to your application.

Example:

Change the client id, secret, and scope in this URI to the ones you are using. then paste it into a browser location bar.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope={scope}&response_type=code
```

[image]

It will prompt you for authentication. If you click except you get another window with a long code in it looking something like this.

[image]

That is the Authentication code, its only purpose in life is for you to use it to get an access token and a refresh token.  It can only be used **once**, and its probably short lived though I have never tested how long they are good for.

In the uri above Note: the response type code.

Exchange:

Once you have that authentication code you need to exchange it for an access token and a refresh token.   this is a HTTP POST so cant be placed in a browser window.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Note: grant_type=authorization_code this tells the server you are sending it an authorization code.

**response**

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

You now have an access token that can be used to access the Google APIs, it is short live lasts only 3600 seconds or 1 hour.  After that you must use the refresh token to get access again.

**Use refreshtoken**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

**response**

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Now that you understand all of that

```
"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"Code was already redeemed."
```

means that you are sending the authorization code again you can only use it once you should be sending the refresh token again.   There is something up with your authentication flow.  Again sorry I cant help with the ruby part.

code ripped from [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, great answer! Will try it out when I get home. One question, the redirect_uri you use in your first call looks interesting. Do you think my issues could be related to using the wrong URI?

Comment: that's the redirect uri for a native application,  basically windows.exe or a phone app probably.   It just means localhost.   Redirect URI just tells the authentication server where to return the authentication code to.

Comment: btw you might want to consider https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client  Google's client librarys are normally very stable and documented.  the other one looks like a fork though wonder what the difference is

Comment: Thanks again for your answer DalmTo, still haven't got it to work though. Pretty sure that I only use the `Authorization code` once. Added my javascript code that get called whenever a user clicks the sign in button, hopefully that can give you some more ideas. Thanks!